# SonarQube's duplication density does not match formula provided by documentations

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube Community Edition Version 7.7. I am having trouble understanding how the value for duplication density is derived.

From the documentation:

```
Duplicated lines (%) (duplicated_lines_density)
= duplicated_lines / lines * 100
```

Most of my SonarQube projects have a duplicated density that does not match the given formula.
[An example from one of my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzTTJ.png)

From the screenshot, the duplication density should have been `41,834/957*100 = 2.3%`, but the value given by SonarQube is `1.4%`.

Did I misunderstood how the duplication density should be calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found out that it was a bug that got fixed in version 7.8.
[Bug ticket here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-12188)